# Linq query equivalent of exists with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql, exists

I've been using linq for a little while now but haven't come across this situation anywhere and my google-fu let me down.

Basically I have two data sets which I did not define and now have to use to return data.

```
class Header 
{
    string COMPANY_CODE
    string REFERENCE_NBR
    string REFERENCE_DUPLICATE
    ...
}

class Line 
{
    string COMPANY_CODE
    string REFERENCE_NBR
    string REFERENCE_DUPLICATE
    string STOCK_CODE
    string DESCRIPTION
    ...
}
```

From a database perspective they join like this

```
select *
from Header
inner join Line
    on header.COMPANY_CODE = Line.COMPANY_CODE
    and header.REFERENCE_NBR = Line.REFERNCE_NBR
    and header.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE = LINE.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE
```

and have a 1:Many relationship.

I'm implementing a search feature for a listing that is meant to find any Lines that with a value in STOCK_CODE or DESCRIPTION that matches a given search term. I have seen a couple of methods of joining using a linq query but because of the multiple join conditions I'm a bit lost and have not found any examples of what I'm trying to do.

If I were to write the statement I am trying to get in lamda/linq in SQL it would be:

```
declare @searchtxt nvarchar(max) = 'test'

Select * 
from header h
where exists (
    select *
    from Line l
    where
        (
            l.stock_code like '%'+@searchtxt+'%' 
            or l.description like '%'+@searchtxt+'%'
        )
        and h.COMPANY_CODE = l.COMPANY_CODE
        and h.REFERENCE_NBR = l.REFERENCE_NBR
        and h.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE = l.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: the sql statement that you provided is perfectly working?

Comment: I've fiddled with the names, so it's slightly different to what I provided but it works. I could just use sql to return the data and then cast it with the type and return that but I'm wanting to find out about linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, this?

```
var result = header.Where(h => 
    Line.Any(l => (l.stock_code.Contains(searchtxt)
                  || l.description.Contains(searchtxt))
               && h.COMPANY_CODE == l.COMPANY_CODE
               && h.REFERENCE_NBR == l.REFERENCE_NBR
               && h.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE == l.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE));
```

Comment: Legend! this is exactly what I was after. I think I should go back and spend some more time getting comfortable with lambda after seeing how simple it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a traditional LINQ query for better understanding,

```
string searchtext = "";
var result = (from h in context.Headers
              join l in context.Lines on new { h.COMPANY_CODE, h.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE, h.REFERENCE_NBR } equals new { l.COMPANY_CODE, l.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE, l.REFERENCE_NBR }
              where l.STOCK_CODE.Contains(searchtext) || l.DESCRIPTION.Contains(searchtext)
              select new
              {
                  COMPANY_CODE = h.COMPANY_CODE,
                  STOCK_CODE = l.STOCK_CODE

                  //You can select more fields from "h" and "l"
              }).ToList();
```

**Edit:**

```
string searchtext = "";
var result = (from h in context.Headers
              join l in context.Lines on new { h.COMPANY_CODE, h.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE, h.REFERENCE_NBR } equals new { l.COMPANY_CODE, l.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE, l.REFERENCE_NBR }
              where l.STOCK_CODE.Contains(searchtext) || l.DESCRIPTION.Contains(searchtext)
              select h
              )
              .GroupBy(x => new { x.COMPANY_CODE, x.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE, x.REFERENCE_NBR })
              .Select(x => x.First())
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the method you used to join will definitely come in handy. The overall query wasn't quite what what I was after as the Join causes multiple rows to return if do => "select h" instead of building a new object. Easy enough to work with though.

Comment: Answer updated. view **Edit** section in answer. this will return only one record of particular header

Answer (score 0):

```
   db.Header.Join(
            db.Line,
            h => new { h.COMPANY_CODE, h.REFERENCE_NBR, h.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE },
            l => new { l.COMPANY_CODE, l.REFERENCE_NBR, l.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE },
            (h, l) => new
            {
                Header_COMPANY_CODE = h.COMPANY_CODE,
                Header_REFERENCE_NBR = h.REFERENCE_NBR,
                Header_REFERENCE_DUPLICATE = h.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE,
                Line_Company_Code = l.COMPANY_CODE,
                Line_REFERENCE_NBR = l.REFERENCE_NBR,
                Line_REFERENCE_DUPLICATE = l.REFERENCE_DUPLICATE,
                Line_STOCK_CODE = l.STOCK_CODE,
                Line_DESCRIPTION = l.DESCRIPTION
            }
            )
            .Where(w => w.Line_STOCK_CODE.Contains(searchText) || w.Line_DESCRIPTION.Contains(searchText))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I was after. This returns data from the Line entity. I was not after any data from those lines, just the header records which they are attached too.